Options for wiring a switch and lights with minimal wire length
Preface: I am new to electrical and am doing this project DIY but will have it inspected to pass code.
I am wiring an office room with a switch and 4 lights. My understanding is the wire from the sub panel must first go to the switch, then from the switch to the lights as show in Option #1. Because of the door and window placements, this ends up using around 75 ft of 12/2 wire.
Option #2 is my ideal scenario but I don't know all the details to pull this off. It would require only about 50 ft of wire.
Can I make 3-way junctions, splice the wires, and still have the switch control the power to the lights? It seems like power would run continuously to the lights if I splice the hot from the light to the power source hot.
I only have 12/2 wire right now, does a 3-way junction require 12/3?



I'm not an electrician but I think if it's just lights on this circuit you can use 14 gauge as opposed to 12 gauge. That should save you some money.

Only if the breaker is 15A, @PlatinumGoose

The cost of the cable itself is small compared to the effort involved in optimizing the run, particularly if you need to get /3 cable to run to the light first. A 250' roll of cable from an electrical supply shop ran me about the same as a 100' roll from the big box store. Spend a small bit more (or ahop elsewhere) on the cable now and make your install much easier

You are making simple stuff complicated.
Just run the cable from the panel to the switch and out to the lights. Using junction boxes to save some wire could just cause a nightmare if there is an issue in the future.
Additionally since each box must have a hot and neutral, (Switch loops are not allowed now.) you may not save as much wire as you think you would.

I'm notorious for complicating simple things until I really understand the topic. Thank you for the quick reply. I'll just buy some more wire and keep it simple!

If it will save significant wiring distance due to layout, bring power (on /2 cable) from the breaker panel to whatever light is most convenient to reach from the breaker box and to reach to the switch. You may need a larger junction box at that light due to wire count, depending on what size you have in place now (if there is one now.)
Run /3 cable to the switch location from that light location for a code legal switch loop. Power does not need to "first go to the switch" but that is the simplest way to ensure that "neutral is available at the switch location" which is required since NEC2011. /3 cable allows you to meet that requirement after stopping at one of the light locations while having the always hot and switched hot you need to have a functional switch.
Run /2 cable from that light location to all other lights.
Connect all whites. Connect breaker black to switch loop black. Connect switch loop red to light blacks.
You can use a separate junction box, though there is no point at all in using TWO separate junction boxes as illustrated. But if you use a separate junction box it always has to be accessible, and it can complicate troubleshooting since it will have to be found. Keeping the junctions at the lights and switches simplifies finding them for the next person (even if that's you, but you forgot about it.)
However, due to the differential price of /3 cable, (.vs /2 cable pricing) using more /2 cable as in option 1 may cost you less. You'll have to check your local pricing, or what you have on hand for cable, to  make that decision.
